# How to code quadratic form both naively and efficiently

Tags: r, quadratic

I'm trying to code a quadratic form Z'(S)^{-1} Z

The code is as below

```
z <- matrix(rnorm(200 * 100), 200, 100)
S <- cov(z)
quad.naive <- function(z, S) {
        Sinv <- solve(S)
        rowSums((z %*% Sinv) * z) 
}
```

However, I'm not sure I understand thoroughly the last line of the function

```
rowSums((z %*% Sinv) * z)
```

Because naively, we should just type exactly the same as the mathematical formula which is

```
t(Z) %*% Sinv %*% Z
```

So, anyone can explain why is the row sums form the same as the naive mathematical form, esp. why after two metrics (z, and Sin) multiplication, it use a element-wise multiply symbol * to times Z, rather than use %*%.

```
(z %*% Sinv) * z
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, following our exchange in the comments and the link you gave to the relevant section in the book [Advanced Statistical Computing](https://bookdown.org/rdpeng/advstatcomp/textbooks-vs-computers.html#multivariate-normal-distribution) I *think* I understand what the issue is.

I post this a separate (and real) answer, to avoid confusing future readers who may want to read through the train of thoughts in the comments.

---

Let's return to the code given in your post (which is copied from section 1.3.3 Multivariate Normal Distribution)

```r
set.seed(2017-07-13)
z <- matrix(rnorm(200 * 100), 200, 100)
S <- cov(z)
quad.naive <- function(z, S) {
        Sinv <- solve(S)
        rowSums((z %*% Sinv) * z)
}
```

Considering that the quadratic form is defined as the scalar quantity `z' Sigma^-1 z` (or in R language `t(z) %*% solve(Sigma) %*% z`) for a random p × 1 column vector, two questions may arise:

1. Why is `z` given as a `matrix` (instead of a `p`-dimensional column vector, as stated in the book), and
2. what is the reason for using `rowSums` in `quad.naive`?

First off, keep in mind that the quadratic form is a scalar quantity for a single random multivariate sample. What `quad.naive` is actually returning is the *distribution* of the quadratic form in multivariate samples (plural!). `z` here contains 200 samples from a `p = 100`-dimensional normal.

Then `S` is the 100 x 100 covariance matrix, and `solve(S)` returns the inverse matrix of `S`. The quantity `z %*% Sinv * z` (the additional brackets are not necessary due to R's operator precedence) returns the diagonal elements of `t(z) %*% solve(Sigma) %*% z` for every sample of `z` as row vectors in a matrix. Taking the `rowSums` is then the same as taking the trace (i.e. having the quadratic form return a scalar for every sample). Also note that you get the same result with `diag(z %*% solve(Sigma) %*% t(z))`, but in `quad.naive` we avoid the double matrix multiplication and additional transposition.

---

A more fundamental question remains: Why look at the distribution of quadratic forms? It can be shown that the distribution of certain quadratic forms in standard normal variables follows a chi-square distribution (see e.g. [Mathai and Provost, Quadratic Forms in Random Variables: Theory and Applications](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/224817325_Quadratic_Forms_in_Random_Variables_Theory_and_Applications) and [Normal distribution - Quadratic forms](https://www.statlect.com/probability-distributions/normal-distribution-quadratic-forms))

Specifically, we can show that the quadratic form (x - μ)' Σ^-1 (x - μ) for a p × 1 column vector is chi-square distributed with p degrees of freedom.

To illustrate this, let's draw 100 samples from a bivariate standard normal, and calculate the quadratic forms for every sample.

```
set.seed(2020)
nSamples <- 100
z <- matrix(rnorm(nSamples * 2), nSamples, 2)
S <- cov(z)
Sinv <- solve(S)
dquadform <- rowSums(z %*% Sinv * z)
```

We can visualise the distribution as a histogram and overlay the theoretical chi-square density for 2 degrees of freedom.

```
library(ggplot2)
bw = 0.2
ggplot(data.frame(x = dquadform), aes(x)) +
    geom_histogram(binwidth = bw) +
    stat_function(fun = function(x) dchisq(x, df = 2) * nSamples * bw)
```

[image]

Finally, results from a Kolmogorov-Smirnov test comparing the distribution of the quadratic forms with the cumulative chi-square distribution with 2 degrees of freedom lead us to fail to reject the null hypothesis  (of the equality of both distributions).

```
ks.test(dquadform, pchisq, df = 2)
#
#   One-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test
#
#data:  dquadform
#D = 0.063395, p-value = 0.8164
#alternative hypothesis: two-sided
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your such detailed explanation! I think now I understand every single piece of it. 1). So normally, the z should be a p * 1 vector, hence the quadratic form z' Sinv z is a scalar. But in the example, the Z is 200 of transposed p * 1 vectors row bind together. So the result is actually a distribution of quadratic forms (scalars). Thank you for your great extending to that such distribution is actually Chi-squared!

Comment: cont'd 2). rowSums(z %*% Sinv * z) is the same as diag( z %*% Sinv %*% t(z)) , but save flops.

Comment: cont'd The website is a great resource! Thank you for sharing! But I also have another confusion which is not introduced on this website, which is about Matrix differentiation.  e.g. d (X' A X) / dX = X' (A + A'). Such kind of differentiation which is a bit different from the rules directly used in univariate differentiation. I'm not sure whether you have any good methods or books to recommend. I self-read wikipedia, and some lecture notes searched on line. But would prefer some more formal reading material. Thank you!

Comment: some people suggest the Matrix Cookbook. but I don't think it's a good one as it only has results but no proof.

Comment: @skylar In response to your points 1) the quadratic form is *always* a scalar (there is no "normally, the z should be ..."); what we're looking at here is the *distribution* of quadratic forms, which is a vector. 2) yes, I think that's advantage of using `rowSums`; but keep in mind that this is still not very computationally efficient/stable as we still need to invert a matrix. Cholesky decomposition gets around that.

Comment: [continued] In response to your new question: You should close this question by setting the green checkmark next to an answer and then ask a new question. SO has a one question at a time policy which makes it easier for future readers to identify relevant/interessant questions.

Comment: @skylar Concerning matrix differentiation: it helps to rewrite X' A X in terms of the individual components; i.e. X' A X = sum_{i=0}^n sum_{j=0}^n a_{ij} X_i X_j; then differentiate using the product rule, and rewrite in "compact" matrix form. I would say a good linear algebra book would be a good starting point for some self-study. Back in my days at uni, linear algebra books were awfully dry but I think you can find some nice books with a more practical and modern approach if you look around a bit on e.g. Amazon/bookdepository.

Answer (score 3):

The following is a bit too long for a comment.

*"I'm trying to code a quadratic form Z'(S)^{-1} Z"* I don't think the quadratic form is correct.

Assume `Z` is a `m x n` matrix. Then:

- `S = cov(Z)` is a `n x n` matrix
- `S^-1` is a `n x n` matrix
- `t(Z)` is a `n x m` matrix

So `Z' S^-1 Z` (in R: `t(Z) %*% solve(S) %*% Z`) would mean multiplying matrices with the following dimensions

```
(n x m) (n x m) (m x n)
```

which obviously won't work.

Perhaps you meant `Z %*% solve(S) %*% t(Z)` which returns a `m x m` matrix, the diagonal of which is the same as `rowSums(Z %*% Sinv * Z)`.

More fundamentally: Shouldn't the [quadratic form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_form_(statistics)) be a scalar? Or are you talking about a different quadratic form?

Comment: Dear Maurits, thank you very much for your answers, which clarified one of my confusions, so considering the size, the naive way to code is `Z %*% solve(S) %*% t(Z)` . But when you say the diagonal of the resulting m by m matrix is the same as `rowSums(Z %*% Sinv * Z)`.  Why do we need to think about the diagonal of the quadratic matrix? shouldn't we focus on the quadratic form and its resulting matrix? Thank you!

Comment: Is it because the result is essentially a scalar, so the diagonal of the scalar is itself? In addition, I find it hard to image the 'rowSums(Z %*% Sinv * Z)'. The first part Z %*% Sinv should result an m by n matrix, then the code uses this matrix to time z element-wisely, and finally take the sum of each row of the resulting m by n matrix.  Thank you!

Comment: @skylar *"Is it because the result is essentially a scalar, so the diagonal of the scalar is itself?"* I struggle to understand what that means. The diagonal of a matrix is exactly what it says: it's the diagonal elements of a matrix. The *trace* of a matrix is the sum of the diagonal elements, which is a scalar. Commonly, the quadratic form in random variables is a scalar. I don't know where your definition of quadratic forms comes from. I have a feeling this is somewhat of an XY problem, but without knowing your background or the context, I can't really help.

Comment: [continued 1] In regards to how `rowSums` works here. Consider two matrices `A <- matrix(c(1:6), ncol = 3); B <- matrix(c(1:6), ncol = 2)`. Then we can calculate the trace as `sum(diag(A %*% B))` or as `sum(rowSums(A * t(B)))`. I imagine the second option being slightly faster as it avoids matrix multiplication.

Comment: [continued 2] I've got a feeling this comes down to a misunderstanding about what a quadratic form is. As far as I understand, in the original code for `quad.naive` the argument `z` should be a vector of `n` observations of a random variable and not a matrix.

Comment: @Marrits, thank you for your response! I completely understand the two ways you mentioned to calculate the trace, but my question is how calculating a quadratic form will eventually end up with calculating a trace.

Comment: [con'd] My thought then extends to if the quadratic form is a scalar, then it might be equivalent to some sum of diagonals, hence the trace.

Comment: [Cont'd] If as you said, the z is a p by 1 vector, then cov(z) will just return a number rather than a matrix. so it seems not working.

Comment: @skylar I think we're missing each others points. Where does the definition *"Z'(S)^{-1} Z"* come from? Where does the function `quad.naive` come from? Neither of those "definitions" (the first one being obviously wrong), returns a scalar for your choice of `z` (which oddly is a `matrix`). There's no mention of a trace. Without context/background, I'm afraid I can't really help as I don't understand what you're trying to do (hence my comment that this sounds like an XY problem).

Comment: @Maruits Thank you for your follow up! The original concept originates from the online book I'm currently reading, the multivariate Normal example https://bookdown.org/rdpeng/advstatcomp/textbooks-vs-computers.html#multivariate-normal-distribution

Comment: @skylar I've posted an [extended (and separate) answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59837498/6530970), please take a look.